# Error during finding the link text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
Proxy element for: org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator
```

@FindBy(xpath="//By.partialLinkText('Customer Info - Primus')")

Please tell me what is wrong in code.The link is not clickable. 
Thanks
Neeraj

Comment: try `xpath="//a[contains(text(),'Customer Info - Primus')]`. We'd be able to help you better, if you provide the complete code.

Comment: @Test
 public static void vrifyvalidclient() throws IOException, InterruptedException
 {
  Login_Page Lobj=new Login_Page();
  Home_Page Hobj=Lobj.validlogin();
  Customerinfo_Primus CPrimusobj= Hobj.click_customerinfoprimus();
  
 }

Comment: Please edit the original question and put the additional code in there and properly format it. It will be more likely seen there instead of in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try Xpath as below:-

```
//*[contains(text(),'Customer Info - Primus')]
```

So your statement will be somthing like:-

```
xpath="//*[contains(text(),'Customer Info - Primus')]"
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: This is working fine in normal script :DriverObject.findElement(By.linkText("Customer Info - Primus")).click();

Comment: I want to set in POM using FindBy but the error is $Proxy5 for webelement

Comment: Not able to hit the target in selenium IDE also

Answer (score 0):

On observing this @FindBy(xpath="//By.partialLinkText('Customer Info - Primus')") it looks like some confusion here. Here specifying as xpath = but trying to give PartialLinkText, know that these two are object location strategies.

Can you try

```
  @FindBy(partialLinkText="Customer Info - Primus")
```

If this partial link text not working as expected, try with xpath

```
 @FindBy(xpath="//*[contains(text(),'Customer Info - Primus')]")
```

if xpath also not working as expected, please provide HTML code of element to help you with correct locator.

Thank You,
Murali